# Wordpress loop: custom field value 'yes' > order by taxonomy 'a' and custom field value 'no' > order by taxonomy 'b'

Tags: wordpress, loops, taxonomy, custom-fields

Tried searching and testing for two days now, but don't seem to get this loop working in the way that I want it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

1. I want to loop through a custom post type (I know how to do this)
2. In this loop, I first would like to list a few posts (number can vary) with a custom field value ('yes'), and then sort these posts based on a taxonomy value (length).
3. Then I would like to list the rest of the posts (these have a custom field value 'no') and sort these posts based on a taxonomy value (year).

These pages use pagination. I tried two different loops but since the first part is an undefined number of posts, this does not work for me. And on top of that it just feels 'cleaner' in one loop if possible.

So far this is what I have:

```
<?php $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'custom-post-type-name',
   'posts_per_page' => 24,
   'paged' => $paged,
   'meta_query' => array(
      'first-posts' => array(
         'meta_key' => 'highlighted-post',
         'meta_value' => 'yes',
       ),
      'other-posts' => array(
         'meta_key' => 'highlighted-post',
         'meta_value' => 'no'
      ), 
   ),
   'orderby' => array(
      'first-posts' => 'ASC',
      'other-posts' => 'DESC'
   ),
); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make two queries, one for the 'yes' posts and another for the 'no'. Also, your query is wrong when calling meta query.

We set the pagination:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
```

The 'yes' posts:

```
<?php $yes_posts = get_posts(array(
   'post_type' => 'custom-post-type-name',
   'posts_per_page' => 24,
   'paged' => $paged,
   'meta_query' => array(
     array(
         'meta_key' => 'highlighted-post',
         'meta_value' => 'yes',
       ),
   ),
   'order' => 'ASC'
)); ?>
```

The 'no' posts:

```
<?php $no_posts = get_posts(array(
   'post_type' => 'custom-post-type-name',
   'posts_per_page' => 24,
   'paged' => $paged,
   'meta_query' => array(
      array(
         'meta_key' => 'highlighted-post',
         'meta_value' => 'no'
      ), 
   ),
   'orderby' => 'DESC'
)); ?>
```

We combine the queries to get a list of post ids for the last query:

```
$allposts = array_merge($yes_posts, $no_posts);
$postids = array();
foreach( $allposts as $item ) {
    $postids[] = $item->ID;
}
```

We create an array of post IDs

```
$unique = array_unique($postids);
$args = array(
    'post__in' => $unique,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'orderby' => 'post__in'
);
```

We do the loop:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $checking = 0;
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { $the_query->the_post();
        // Handle posts here
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Combine every code in a page and it should work.